# Trying to Insert Form Data to DB but Error

Tags: codeigniter

**TWO Errors**

### Error 1

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant model_users - assumed 'model_users'

Filename: controllers/main.php

Line Number: 110
```

### Error 2

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Main::$add_database

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51
```

### Controller

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
{
    $this->load->model(model_users);          //Line 110
    $this->model_users->add_database;
}else{
    $this->load->view('signup');
}
```

**Model**

```
public function add_database() {


$usersdata = array (
                'email'     =>  $this->input->post('email'),
                'password'  =>  md5($this->input->post('password')),
);

$regdetails = array (
                'full_name'         =>  $this->input->post('full_name'),
                'gender'            =>  $this->input->post('gender'),
                'dob'               =>  $this->input->post('dob'),
                'address'           =>  $this->input->post('address'),
                'city'              =>  $this->input->post('city'),
                'state'             =>  $this->input->post('state'),
                'country'           =>  $this->input->post('country'),
                'pin'               =>  $this->input->post('zip'),
                'alternative_email' =>  $this->input->post('alt_email'),
                'phone'             =>  $this->input->post('phone'),
                'mobile'            =>  $this->input->post('mobile'),
);


    $query = $this->db->insert('users',$usersdata);
    $this->db->insert('tbl_studentreg',$regdetails);
}
```

May I know How to fix it? without coming future errors in above mention code. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed `"`.. pass your model name as string...

```
 $this->load->model("model_users");
```

[docs here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html)

second error ,

you need to add `()` , since you are calling a function called add_database

```
 $this->model_users->add_database();
```

Comment: Ya Bipen, that Error Fixed . thanks alot 


BUT

how about Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51 

May I know how to fix that too?

Comment: thanks Bipen. Fixed the Problem and Data is inserted.

I have a small doubt too

Can I Write this two line as one single line ? 

$query = $this->db->insert('users',$usersdata);
$this->db->insert('tbl_studentreg',$regdetails);

for Ref : check above Question Model

Comment: I have a small doubt too Can I Write this two line as one single line ? 

$query = $this->db->insert('users',$usersdata); 

$this->db->insert('tbl_studentreg',$regdetails); 

for Ref : check above Question Model –

Comment: why do u need that.. the one you have is correct...... inserting into two DB tables from a single line is not possible.. you need to run two insert queries anyhow..

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for loading the model is wrong.. just specify the name of you model as string 
it will look like this.

```
$this->load->model("model_users");
```

if again error is occuring then check the name you specify for the model 
your line may be like this.

```
class Model_users extends CI_Model{
```

}

Answer (score 0):

have you loaded the database library in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```